# Including external code with dom structure in my script

Tags: javascript

I have a script generating DOM elements:

```
// ...
function generate(ajaxResponse) {
   var container = Element.createContainer(ajaxResponse);
   var titleDiv = Element.createTitleDiv();
   container.appendChild(titleDiv);
   var otherDiv = Element.createOtherDiv();
   container.appendChild(otherDiv);
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(container);
}
function Element() {
   return {
      'createContainer': function(ajaxResponse) {
         //...
      },
      // ...
   };
}
// ...
```

Many users will use this script - I want to enable for each one the possibility to write his own `html/css`. So I'd like to create some wysiwyg editor where user will be able to write his own javascript structure, and then I'll load this structure from the database in the script:

```
  // ...
    function generate(ajaxResponse) {
       Api.getHTMLFromDatabase(function(response) {
          response;
       });
       document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(container);
    }
    function Element() {
       return {
          Api.getStylesFromDatabase(function(response) {
             response;
          });
          },
          // ...
       };
    }
    // ...
```

So I'd like it to look like that. I've been thinking about eval, but:
1. It's bad design solution
2. There are variables like `ajaxResponse` that I have to use from my original script inside those external script.

What would be a nice solution to this problem?

Comment: may be use reactjs ?

Comment: I can't use any libraries like jQuery or reactjs or angular, it ought to be clean js.